# Asp.net Chart control in SharePoint 2010

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint-2010, charts

Can anyone help me in storing Chart control's temporary images in SharePoint 2010 Document library/Picture library? Whether it is possible or not ? Actually want to use a webpart with Chart control in it, in a load balanced environment.

Answer (score 1):

I think I got a answer for my query, to store the chart images in SharePoint document library we need to map a document library to a hard disc drive (as I did z:) and then set the chart image handler as:  for this to work porperly we also need to change the script manager's async postback timeout property to 3600 as AsyncPostBackTimeOut="3600". The process is taking around 3 minutes (as it first creating the chart images in document library and then downloading those) in my environment which is bit high for the users to wait that much long :( so again searching for some methods that can make the process faster. Hope this can help someone.

Answer (score 0):

The information in the document library is stored in the database so there should be no issues with keeping images there across a load-balanced environment.
The images in a document/image library are all URL accessible resources so you should be able to populate ImageLocation property of the chart control and set ImageStorageMode to ImageStorageMode.UseImageLocation.
Encapsulating that in the web part should not make any difference than a user control.  You may elect to provision the image library and the web part in the same site coll feature.

Comment: Hi Roman, Is it possible for you to help us with one of our Sharepoint webparts where were facing the same issue as mentioned in the question above?

Comment: @NitinSrivastava Create a question and link to it, i'd be happy to review and community will help as well.

Comment: @Roman, thnx for your rplies, I tried to save the image as you mentioned, in a picture library, but it gives me javascript error as : `Message: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: 'http://sp2010/Chart/Chart_000001.png' is not a valid virtual path.` I used : `chart.ImageLocation = "http://sp2010/Chart/Chart_#SEQ(50,5)";
  chart.ImageStorageMode = ImageStorageMode.UseImageLocation;`

Comment: @Roman: I had a discussion with my manager. He had asked if you would like to work as a paid consultant for this task? If yes, please let me know, I will pass on the word to them

Comment: @DeepakSemwal feel free to contact me through my blog. We can discuss further.  
I think if it's quick task, i can just help out. The reason to keep it open is so that the community benefit as well.
Can you provide the steps how you attempted to save the file? Is that within code?
I'll try to cook up a sample as well tonight.

Comment: @Roman: I tried to save the file in picture library using code as : `string newUrl = SPContext.Current.Web.Url +"/"+ [doclib].RootFolder.Url; // where doclib is your imageslibrary 
chart.ImageLocation =  newUrl ;chart.ImageStorageMode=ImageStorageMode.UseImageLocation;` But this gives me error as : `Message: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: 'http://sp2010/Chart/Chart_000001.png' is not a valid virtual path`.

Comment: @DeepakSemwal sorry to send you on a chase for a little bit, i should have researched a bit more thoroughly.  Basically, the Charting control UseImageLocation property instructs the control to store the image using put to the URL location, therefore it wont work obviously.  I am still looking at an alternative where it might be possible to overwrite the IHttpHandler and write custom IChartStorageHandler implementation that SP aware. This would require some development indeed.